# AWS Glue produces invalid JSON when writing dynamic frame

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm testing out AWS Glue write functions and I wanted to write some JSON to S3. So, I have the following snippet:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
glue_context = GlueContext(spark)

df = glue_context.createDataFrame(
    [
        {'name': 'Aaron', 'age': 25, 'function': 'Engineering'},
        {'name': 'Baron', 'age': 35, 'function': 'Product'},
        {'name': 'Caron', 'age': 45, 'function': 'Marketing'},
        {'name': 'Daron', 'age': 55, 'function': 'Sales'}
    ]
)
dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
    dataframe=df,
    glue_ctx=glue_context,
    name='dyf',
)
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dyf.coalesce(1),
    connection_type='s3',
    connection_options={'path': 's3://awsglue/test_write'},
    format='json',
)
```

This produces a file in S3 with the following contents:

```
{"age":25,"function":"Engineering","name":"Aaron"}
{"age":35,"function":"Product","name":"Baron"}
{"age":45,"function":"Marketing","name":"Caron"}
{"age":55,"function":"Sales","name":"Daron"}
```

That is not valid JSON. Now if I'm not mistaken this output is Spark's doing. So is Spark output only intended to be interpreted by Spark? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [by spark's design](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json.html):

> pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(...)
>
> Saves the content of the DataFrame in JSON format (JSON Lines text
> format or newline-delimited JSON) at the specified path.

So each record is valid json, but the whole file is newline delimited